# Printing only the first weights of a neural network

Tags: deep-learning, parameters, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have my model (a VGG16, but it is not important). I want to check only some parameters of my network, for example the first ones.
To do this I do `list(model.parameters())` and it prints all the parameters.
Now, considering that a VGG has this shape:

```
VGG16(
  (block_1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (2): ReLU()
    (3): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (4): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (5): ReLU()
    (6): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
...
```

If I want only the weights of the convolutions I do this: `list(model.block_1[0].parameters())` and it prints this:

```
[Parameter containing:
 tensor([[[[-0.3215, -0.0771,  0.4429],
           [-0.6455, -0.0827, -0.4266],
           [-0.2029, -0.2288,  0.1696]]],
 
 
         [[[ 0.5323, -0.2418, -0.1031],
           [ 0.5917,  0.2669, -0.5630],
           [ 0.3064, -0.4984, -0.1288]]],
 
 
         [[[ 0.3804,  0.0906, -0.2116],
           [ 0.2659, -0.3325, -0.1873],
           [-0.5044,  0.0900,  0.1386]]],
```

Now, these lists are always enormous. How can I print only the first values, for example, the first matrix?

```
[[[[-0.3215, -0.0771,  0.4429],
   [-0.6455, -0.0827, -0.4266],
   [-0.2029, -0.2288,  0.1696]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat it as a NumPy array when it's processed correctly. In your example, this should work:

```py
from torchvision import models
model = models.vgg16()
first_param = list(model.features[0].parameters())[0].data
```

The `first_param` will hold the tensor as:

```py
tensor([[[[-0.3215, -0.0771,  0.4429],
           [-0.6455, -0.0827, -0.4266],
           [-0.2029, -0.2288,  0.1696]]],
 
 
         [[[ 0.5323, -0.2418, -0.1031],
           [ 0.5917,  0.2669, -0.5630],
           [ 0.3064, -0.4984, -0.1288]]],
 
 
         [[[ 0.3804,  0.0906, -0.2116],
           [ 0.2659, -0.3325, -0.1873],
           [-0.5044,  0.0900,  0.1386]]]
```

Then just continue as NumPy array:

```py
print(first_param[0])

>> tensor([[[[-0.3215, -0.0771,  0.4429],
             [-0.6455, -0.0827, -0.4266],
             [-0.2029, -0.2288,  0.1696]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice Tensorflow tensors with the same syntax as Python lists. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[[[-0.3215, -0.0771,  0.4429],
       [-0.6455, -0.0827, -0.4266],
       [-0.2029, -0.2288,  0.1696]]],

     [[[ 0.5323, -0.2418, -0.1031],
       [ 0.5917,  0.2669, -0.5630],
       [ 0.3064, -0.4984, -0.1288]]],

     [[[ 0.3804,  0.0906, -0.2116],
       [ 0.2659, -0.3325, -0.1873],
       [-0.5044,  0.0900,  0.1386]]]])

print(tensor[0, :])
```

This will give you the first matrix from your example, together with related shape information. If you want to get rid of this shape information, you could, for instance, convert the sliced tensor into a numpy array with `print(np.array(tensor[0, :]))`.

Comment: The problem is that parameters are type Generator. My model.block_1[0] already gives the first parameters, which is a long list (I showed the first ones in the post). So, I need something like this: `list(model.block_1[0][0].parameters())` but then I have this error: `TypeError: 'Conv2d' object is not subscriptable`